# Stop xlsx import into MSSQL with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, xlsx

This snippet works fine, the problem is that it will never stop and it keeps filling my database with the same values fom xlsx, over and over again (when the last entry is done, it starts again with the first one). How can I stop the run when the import is finished?

excel.js

```
rfr = require('rfr');
knex = rfr('db');
xlsxj = require("xlsx-to-json");
xlsxj({
  input: "./users.xlsx",
  sheet: "Sheet5",
  output: "./asd.json"
}, function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    result.forEach(element => {
      knex('customers').insert({
        name: element['Name'],
        email: element['Email'],
        group: element['Group'],
      }).then({
      })
    });
  }
});
```

index.js

```
require('excel.js')
app.listen(3001, () => console.log('Server started at port: 3001'));
```

Comment: I tried your snippet with `console.log` instead of `knex.insert` and it works fine.

Comment: Ahh, good idea. I did that too and the result was ok indeed; the problem was that I was running the program with `nodemon` instead of `node`. Thank you!

Comment: I see. You could add an answer to your own question, it might help others running into the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mihai said in the comments, there was no problem with the code itself, but with the way I was running it. Instead of `nodemon` I ran with `node` and everything went fine. (with `nodemon`, the program was restarting after every `knex.insert` and it was writing the data over and over again)